# White border around icons

Tags: themes, icons

I am having a problem where there is a white square that is visible across every icon. I have attached a snapshot to show the problem.

This problem arose while I was using Gnome Shell and the Faience theme. I am using 12.10, and have tried resetting the desktop to default unity and gnome 3 settings but it did not help.

[image]

Comment: NOTE: only *.desktop files are like this. You have a link to your home folder in the upper left corner and also a text file in the middle that do NOT have the border. I've tried this and it doesn't happen with actual files or folders created on the desktop.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! See other comments for the links to the bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the GNOME3 ppa?

This seems a bug with the latest nautilus 3.6.3 update.

Anyone know how to file a bug report with that?

Comment: Bugs of nautilus seem not tracked by launchpad. I got "This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again." when using ubuntu-bug.

Comment: Yes, now that you say I was using Gnome3 ppa, and was using nautilus 3.6.x. I do not recollect the exact minor version.

Comment: @user106593 hmmm, I got the same message in 13.04. Try reporting using the PPA's site as in my updated answer.

Comment: @user106593 Nautilus *is* tracked by Launchpad, something must just be up with the current version we've tried it with.

Comment: I've reported this is [as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1085320) in Launchpad using the web interface.

Answer (score 3):

I also got this when using a recent daily build CD image of Ubuntu 13.04 (no changes, just the default), so this is probably a bug in a new version of Nautilus, as user106593 said.

***EDIT***:  I have reported this as [Bug #1085320](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1085320) in the Launchpad website for Nautilus in Ubuntu.

#### If you are using the version of Nautilus supplied with Ubuntu:

To file a bug report run `ubuntu-bug -w` and click on the desktop. Follow the instructions it gives and attach a picture of what your desktop looks like to the bug report web page. To report the bug, you will need to create an account in [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net).

Another way is to go the the [Bugs page for Nautilus](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus) and click report a bug. The difference is that you don't get the information added by `ubuntu-bug -w` by default. You can still add it later to the report if you want.

For more information see, [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

#### If you are using the GNOME3 PPA:

As user106593 said, `ubuntu-bug` will not work, because the PPA installs a newer version built for the version of Ubuntu you are running. To report a bug in the PPA's software, try using [contacting the team](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+contactuser) (you'll need a Launchpad account) or emailing their mailing list at gnome3-team@lists.launchpad.net (I'm not sure if this will work, since is says subscribing is only open to team members).

Answer (score 0):

I am having this problem also using the gnome 3 shell with ubuntu.

There is a patch found here for those that know how to apply patches in linux.

http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=229370&d=1356937762

Comment: Could you edit your answer to link to the Ubuntu Forums thread instead? That link doesn't work for non-logged in users.

Comment: Here is the tarball with the patch in it for Nautilus, which handles the desktop. Its a bug with the new nautilus 3.6.3 for gnome 3+. Here is the link for that tarball. http://figue.lnx.im/nautilus-3.6.3-1.src.tar.gz