# custom icon has odd border svg?

Tags: icons, directory, customization, desktop-background

I got the default folder .svg from my OS and edited it to add a paintbrush for my artwork folder and I place in in a separate icons folder saved as an .svg when I look at it in the folder it has a odd background/border. even though it has neither.

[image: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/ZC5V4kSX5vYe9OoWJD7g7i8jszwcFqhoTsyVV6jpdcg?feat=directlink]

here's a link a screen shot of the image. I created it with inkscape from the original folder icon located in /usr/share/icons/humanity/places/48/folder.svg

If you look at the artwork icon in the home/pictures folder on the left it has that border. compared to the default just below it.

The svg(right top, displayed bellow showing transparency). I want to get rid of that border

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please include the exact icon (and location) you were trying to edit. Also include what application you used in editing. Including a screenshot would also be very much helpful. Please provide this information by *editing* your question.

Comment: I'm not implying that your question is off-topic here, but you may like http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If the svg file isn't large, you could paste the contents here.

Comment: I think it's best if you upload the xml code somewhere so that people who know about this can guide you.

Comment: Possibly related:http://askubuntu.com/questions/221601/white-border-around-icons

Comment: it does look the same as that bug http://askubuntu.com/questions/221601/white-border-around-icons

Comment: But it says that the bug was patched in Nautilus 3.6.3, did you edited the SVG with Inkscape?